# DDR3 Termination Resistors and VTT Capacitors

Tags: pcb, resistors, memory, termination, ddr3

I have a DDR3 implemented in our current design with 50 Ohm 0402 termination resistors and 0.1uF 0402 decoupling capacitors to VTT on the address, data and control lines. The design is working well but we need to make a new revision and we are short on PCB space. Can these resistors and or capacitors be reduced to 0201 ? What factors do I have to take into consideration ? I looked around and couldn't find any information on this or recommendations about package sizes ?

Comment: I bet you don't have those capacitors connected to the data and address lines.

Comment: Yes, You can go with 0201 package for both resistors & capacitors. For resistors alone you can check power consumption. But we are already using with DDR4 chips.

Answer (score 0):

Since layout and dynamic load switched C and ESR determines the amount of ripple voltage,  You need to choose as many suppliers as you can to qualify, after you define the environmental stress and ripple specs and judge by test results.